# Azure Data Factory merge parquet files by folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADLS Gen2 Account(HNS enabled) with parquet files in this format:

```
-MainFolder
 -SubFolder 1
 -SubFolder 2
   -Year
   -Month
   -Day
     -Parquet file 01
     -Parquet file 02
     -...
```

I want to use Azure Data Factory to combine the parquet files on the lowest level into one file, final structure should look like this.

```
-MainFolder
 -SubFolder 1
 -SubFolder 2
   -Year
   -Month
   -Day
     -Merged Parquet File
```

If I use "Copy Data" Activiety I can only choose between "Merge Files" and "Preserve Hirachie".
Is there away to do this?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Merge Files doesn't work for you in Copy Activity, you can use Data Flow and the Union transformation can combine multiple files into a single file output.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: Let's say you have 2 files from your folder that you wish to combine into 1 file. Set 2 source transformations in your data flow, 1 for each file, use Union to combine them together and output to a new combined single file in the Sink transformation.